# MongoClient Not found connection php mongolab

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to Mongolab db server, but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /home/viviane/public_html/sk/zizi/head.php on line 33
```

I suspect it is related to the PHP Mongo Driver, but I don't know how. If I try to connect to a remote mongodb server

```
 $uri = "mongodb://dzyasser:dzyasser@ds049624.mongolab.com:49624/serverdb";
 $options = array("connectTimeoutMS" => 30000);
    $connection = new MongoClient($uri, $options );
```

So why am I still getting this error when I'm trying to connect to a remote  Mongodb server (Mongolab)?

Comment: Tried to improve grammar and wording, still a bit unclear though.

Answer (score 1):

Its look like you don't have MongoDB PHP extension in your system.

Try to install MongoDB PHP extension in order to solve your problems with the MongoClient class. This is how I setup MongoDB PHP extension in OS X.

1. Get MongoDB extension from PECL

   > $ sudo pecl install mongodb
2. Make a copy of php.ini.default

   > $ sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
3. Put this line on php.ini than save

   > extension=mongodb.so
4. Check the installation using this command

   > php --re mongodb
5. Or create simple php document that contain phpinfo() function

If you get problem with writing the extension, please read this [post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11?share=1).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the Mongo driver is installed and loaded.

If so, since the error message says the `MongoClient` class cannot be found, it might be caused by a namespace used in your script. If so, try

```
$connection = new \MongoClient($uri, $options );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you are connecting locally or remotely, it seems PHP requires the mongo DB service to be running on your server. So install it like so:

a) Install mongodb service

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

b) Add the php drivers if they are missing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear -y
$ sudo pecl install mongo
```

c) Then open your php.ini file and add to it the extension line "extension=mongo.so":

```
$ sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
> extension=mongo.so
```

d) Then restart apache

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Disclaimer: This example was tried on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Apache web-service and PHP5 installed. If your installation is different, follow the same approach but issue appropriate commands. If you have no access to SSH or sudoer privileges, contact someone who can help you do this.